# Why does my while loop never end in my number guess game in C++?

Tags: c++, game-development

I am very new to programming and i am just messing around to try getting this guess a number game working, why once you guess the correct number or run of of lives does it continue?
Thanks!

```
 int rand_number{5};
        int guess_number{};
        int try_number{};
        int player_lifes{5};
        bool game_over{ false };


        cout << "Enter a number between 1-10" << endl;

        while (player_lifes > 0 || game_over == true)
        {
            cout << "You have " << player_lifes << ((player_lifes == 1)? " live left." : " lifes left.") << endl;
            cout << "Your guess is: ";
            cin >> guess_number;
            cout << endl;


            if (guess_number == rand_number)
            {
                int final_lifes = (5 - player_lifes) + 1;
                cout << "well done you solved it in " << final_lifes << (( final_lifes == 1)? " try." : " tries.") << endl << endl;
                game_over = true;

            }
            else
            {
                player_lifes--;
                cout << "wrong try again" << endl;
            }
        }

        cout << "Finished";
```

Comment: If the correct number is guessed, `game_over` is set to `true`.   Once it is set to `true`, there is no code that sets it to `false`.   The loop condition also tests if `player_lifes > 0`  OR if `game_over == true`.   That causes the `while` loop to go forever,  since the loop condition tells it to continue for as long as `game_over` is `true`.     Presumably, you want to change the condition to `player_lifes > 0 && game_over == false` .

Answer (score 4):

```
while (player_lifes > 0 || game_over == true)
```

This means you'll continue looping as long as `player_lifes > 0` OR `game_over == true`.

So this loop can only end when `player_lifes <= 0` AND `game_over == false`. That doesn't sound right...

You probably mean

```
while (player_lifes > 0 && game_over == false)
```

Or in English, "loop while the player has lives AND the game is not over."

In other words, this loop will stop when the opposite is true--when "the player has 0 or less lives OR the game is over."

Comment: Thanks for your response! I set game_over to true once the correct guess has been entered, hoping that once the correct guess was entered the loop would stop, or once you run out of lives.

Comment: @Kevin I edited to add the converse (the condition by which the loop ENDS), to show that it's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`while (player_lifes > 0 || game_over == true)`
This means that the while will run if the `player_lives` are more than 0 (which is correct) **OR** if `game_over` is true.

What you want is to stop the loop as soon as `game_over == true`, and continue when it is false. Your code does the opposite thing! Change it to

```
while (player_lifes > 0 && game_over == false)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have already pointed out the logic error in your code and how to fix it. I want to suggest changes to make your code more readable and easier to write. I suggest using:

```
while ( keep_playing(player_lifes, game_over) )
{
  ...
}
```

where

```
bool player_has_lifes(int player_lifes)
{
   return (player_lifes > 0);
}

bool game_is_not_over(bool game_over)
{
    return (game_over == false);
}

bool keep_playing(int player_lifes, bool game_over)
{
    return (player_has_lifes(player_lifes) && game_is_not_over(game_over));
}
```

---

You can make some of that still easier if you create a `class` to hold the data and add suitable member functions to the class.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I have still to learn about classes which i will be covering in the next couple modules.

Comment: @KevinNisbet, understand. If you feel like it, you may revisit the exercise using `class`es.

Comment: If we're going to discuss naming, I'd argue that the idea of having a `game_over` bool at all is not the greatest. "Game Over" means something other than what's trying to be conveyed with that bool. Maybe it could be `bool num_found;` And then game over could be `bool game_over(int lives, bool num_found) { lives <= 0 || num_found; }` and you'd loop `while( !game_over(lives, num_found) )`. I do appreciate the descriptive function names. This is readable, maintainable code. +1

Comment: @scohe001, good points.